Two different answers for $ I=\int \frac{dx}{1+2\sin^2x+3\cos^2x} $
Evaluate :
$$ I=\int \frac{dx}{1+2\sin^2x+3\cos^2x} $$
My attempt :
By multiplying Numerator and Denominator by $\sec^2x$ and solving I get the value of the integral as $$I_1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt3} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3\ \tan x}{2}\right)+\text{c}$$
By multiplying Numerator and Denominator by $\csc^2x$ and solving I get the value of the integral as $$I_2=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cot x}{\sqrt3}\right) +\text{c}$$
Question :
How is this possible?
Solving by sec²x
Solving by cosec²x

Those two functions are simply the same function.

Yes, I understand that $\frac{1}{2\sqrt3} tan^{-1}  \frac{\sqrt 3 tanx}{2}$ + c can be converted to the second by applying the properties $tan^{-1}x = \frac{\pi}{2} + cot^{-1}x$ and $cot^{-1}\frac{1}{x} = tan^{-1}x +c$
But the domain of the two are different so how can be those two be same functions.
